# Android Studio: What does red exclamation mark on the devices drop-down list mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, connected-components

I showed up at work with an ASUS still plugged in to my computer and Android Studio still running--all just as I left it.  But a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

You are looking at the drop-down to select a device to run.  What exactly does the exclamation mark and green dot mean?  In my head a dot means some sort of message, and a red anything means error.  But green also mean good.  Hmmm.

Comment: It looks like your app's `minSdkVersion` is higher than the API level of the device.

Comment: Yep, changed the gradle (app)'s minSdkVersion and that fixed the exclamation mark (I should have looked at the message more closely!).  But what about the green dot?

Comment: I believe that just means the phone is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I googled [that device](https://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_2_ze551ml-6917.php), and as it says here, it appears to ship out with **Android 5.0 (API level 21)**, upgradable to 6.0. I'm assuming you didn't upgrade it though. The minimum version to run your app is (from the picture) API level 22 = Android 5.1.

So that's probably the explanation - you cannot run the app on that phone since the minimum version you support is lower than your device SDK.

You can sort it out by lowering the `minSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` unless there's a specific reason you're using 22.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  And as Mark said, the green dot means that the device is connected.  Since he has plenty of points, I'll give you the check.  Thanks!